# Azure b2c enrolment

Tags: azure-ad-b2c

We are using b2c for our website, we are trying to integrate with another vendor, they are willing to change their portal to allow our customer to single sign in from our website. Question, how would this flow work, would picture they have a button for enrolment, which allow customer to sign in with b2c credential then they store the credential mapping, then next time whenever customer already login they would automatically login their portal too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would federate your vendor with B2C using either SAML 2.0 or OpenID Connect.

Yes, on the vendor side there would be a "Login with B2C" button.

Once logged in, a cookie is set.

You get SSO as long as the cookie is valid.